# Улучшение страницы справки «Как найти интересующие меня темы?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: How do I find topics I'm interested in?
Ссылка на текущую версию на английском языке: https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

---

Finding specific questions that interest you can be accomplished a few different ways.

### Browse by tag

Every question asked on our site is [tagged](/help/tagging) with the sub-topics that describe it. Each of these tags has its own page that contains a tag wiki and a list of questions with that tag. To find questions about a topic of the site, [visit the Tags page](/tags) and either browse through popular tags or search for a specific one.

Clicking a tag – from anywhere on the site, whether it's from the tag page, or from tags below a question – will show you a list of all questions in that tag and a tag wiki that describes what the tag is and how it is used on this site. You can then sort by unanswered questions, most highly voted questions in that tag, or the newest questions asked with that tag, among others.

If you'd like to be notified of new activity within a certain tag, you can subscribe via email or RSS by hovering over the tag and selecting the method you prefer:

[image: subscribe via email or rss]

### Search tags

If you're looking for questions about multiple topics, you can also [search](/search) by tags. Our site search recognizes tags enclosed in brackets (like this: `[tag]`), as well as the search operators `AND` and `OR`. The default operator is `AND` – i.e., searching for "[tag1] [tag2]" returns posts tagged with both. To search for questions marked with *either* tag, insert an `OR` into your search (e.g., "[tag1] or [tag2]"). For more tips, [visit the search page](/search) and click on "advanced tips".

### Add favorite and ignored tags

Another way to filter out questions you're not interested in and focus on the ones you *do* care about is to add favorite and ignored tags to your account.

**Favorite tags** are meant to call out questions that are important or interesting to you. Any question tagged with one of your favorite tags will be highlighted on the homepage and questions lists.

**Ignored tags** downplay subjects you are not as interested in. Questions with these tags are faded on the homepage and questions list, but are still visible.  If you want to completely hide questions with containing your ignored tags, you may checking the "Hide Ignored Tags" box in the "Preferences" tab of your profile's "Edit Profile & Settings" section on [most sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), or on the "prefs" tab of your profile on certain other sites.

To designate tags as favorite or ignored, click the "add a favorite tag" or "add an ignored tag" link on the right sidebar of the homepage, or in the "prefs" tab of your user profile.

[image: favorite and ignored tags sidebar]

You can also toggle a tag between normal, favorite, or ignored by mousing over the tag and clicking the star icon.

*Normal tag:*

[image: star toggled to normal tag]

*Favorite tag:*

[image: star toggled to favorite tag]

*Ignored tag:*

[image: star toggled to ignored tag]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заголовок: Как найти интересующие меня темы?
Ссылка на текущую версию на русском языке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

---

Найти особые вопросы, которые вас интересуют, можно несколькими способами.

#### Просмотр по метке

Все вопросы, которые задаются на нашем сайте сопровождаются [метками](/help/tagging) с подтемами, которые описывают эти вопросы. Каждой метке назначается собственная страница, содержащая описание метки и список вопросов с этой меткой. Чтобы найти вопросы по теме сайта, перейдите на [страницу меток](/tags) и либо просмотрите популярные метки, либо выполните поиск конкретной метки.

Если вы нажмете метку в любом месте на сайте, на странице метки, или под вопросом, на экран будет выведен список всех вопросов с данной меткой и описание метки, которое объясняет смысл метки и ее применение на данном сайте. Затем вы сможете отсортировать вопросы на неотвеченные вопросы, вопросы с данной меткой, обладающие наибольшим количеством голосов, последние вопросы с этой меткой или другие категории.

Если вы хотите получать уведомления о последних действиях с определенной меткой, вы можете подписаться на рассылку по почте или RSS, удерживая мышку над меткой, выбрав предпочтительный метод.

[image: sample image]

### Поиск по меткам

Если вы ищете вопросы, касающиеся нескольких тем, этот [поиск](/search) также можно выполнить с помощью меток. Поисковый механизм на нашем сайте распознает метки, заключенные в скобки (такие как: `[метка]`), а также операторы поиска `AND` (И) и `OR` (ИЛИ). `AND` является оператором по умолчанию – например, поисковый запрос `[метка1] [метка2]` выведет сообщения, отмеченные обеими метками. Для поиска вопросов, отмеченных одной из этих меток, введите оператор `OR` в запрос (например, `[метка1] or [метка2]`). Более подробную информацию можно найти на [странице поиска](/search) в разделе «расширенные советы».

### Добавление меток в «избранное» или в «игнорируемое»

Другим способом фильтрации вопросов, которые вас не интересуют, и вывода только тех, которые вам требуются, является добавление меток в категории «избранное» или «игнорируемое» в вашей учетной записи.

**Избранные метки** предназначены для поиска вопросов, которые вам важны и интересны. Любой вопрос, отмеченный одной из ваших избранных меток, будет выводиться на главной странице и в списках вопросов.

**Игнорируемые метки** фильтруют темы, которые вам неинтересны. Вопросы с этими метками на главной странице и в списке вопросов выводятся в неконтрастном виде, но, тем не менее, выводятся. Если вы хотите полностью убрать вопросы с игнорируемыми метками, требуется отметить флажком поле «Скрывать вопросы с игнорируемыми метками» на вкладке «настройки предпочтений» в вашем профиле.

Чтобы назначить «избранное» или «игнорируемое» состояние метки, нажмите ссылку «добавить метку в избранное» или «добавить метку в игнорируемые» на правой панели главной страницы или на вкладке «настройки предпочтений» в вашем профиле.

[image: sample image]

Также можно менять состояние метки между «нормальным», «избранным» и «игнорируемым» путем наведения курсора мышки на метку и нажатием символа «звездочка».

*Обычная метка:*

[image: sample image]

*Избранная метка:*

[image: sample image]

*Игнорируемая метка:*

[image: sample image]

Comment: Хм, `AND` при поиске не работает - выводит "показаны результаты содержащие **and**"

Comment: @Андрей вероятно он настолько по умолчанию, что его нельзя использовать явно ;)

Comment: @Андрей Интересно, что `OR` — работает. Причем ситуация одинаковая и у нас, и на SOen. Если получится узнать, обязательно отпишусь!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да просто нет явного AND, вот и все дела. На MSE встречал старые темы, по которым было видно, что раньше по умолчанию был механизм OR.

Comment: @alexolut Возможно тогда стоит убрать соответствующую информацию из справки?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я думаю, стоит уведомить об отсутствии явного AND заокеанских коллег. А то может баг какой в движке поиска, а не в описании.

Comment: @alexolut Да, конечно! Обязательно отпишусь (уже).

Comment: @alexolut На самом деле все работает. Вероятно, мы все спутали поиск по сайту с [поиском по меткам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20and%20golang)! Как я понимаю, это какое–то наследие прошлых версий движка.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это не мы спутали, это ссылка неправильная в справке получается.